# Error in calculating distance

Tags: android, json, dictionary, distance

I found this code for using JSON in calculating distance. I tried to edit it to use it in my project but something went wrong when I click the button.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText e1,e2;
TextView t1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
}
public void d (View view){
    GetRoutDistane(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
public String GetRoutDistane(double startLat, double         startLong, double endLat, double endLong)
{
  String Distance = "error";
  String Status = "error";
  try {
      Log.e("Distance Link : ", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ startLat +e1+ startLong +"&destination="+ endLat +e2+ endLong +"&sensor=false");
        JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ startLat +e1+ startLong +"&destination="+ endLat +e2+ endLong +"&sensor=false"); 
        Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        if(Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
        {
        JSONArray routes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes"); 
         JSONObject zero = routes.getJSONObject(0);
         JSONArray legs = zero.getJSONArray("legs");
         JSONObject zero2 = legs.getJSONObject(0);
         JSONObject dist = zero2.getJSONObject("distance");
         Distance = dist.getString("text");
         t1.setText(Distance.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            Distance = "Too Far";
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return Distance;


} 
public static class parser_Json {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

        //initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //try parse the string to a JSON object
        try{
                jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }

     public static InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            try {

               HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
               final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

               if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 

                  return null;
               }

               HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
               return getResponseEntity.getContent();

            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
               getRequest.abort();

            }

            return null;

         }
    }

}
```

The code didn't give error in Eclipse, but just click on the button leads to a crash.

Comment: Add your logcat also.

Comment: restart your eclipse if your logcat dont show anything

Comment: Yet another NetworkOnMainThredException... Please polish your googling skill before asking

Comment: the logcat dont show any error and i tried to restart it but what is wrong with code id dont know

Comment: Just debug your app and put break point at this line `GetRoutDistane(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission for accessing Internet from your application? If not the crash could be because of this? Also, you are doing a network operation on the main thread so the crash could because of a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as well. After you have checked your internet permissions, please use a thread or an `Asynctask` to run the distance calculator code.

Comment: internet permission is the network full access right

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: im using it mmmm else